# Access jQuery user defined function within said function via sub function

Tags: jquery, function, recursion, user-defined-functions

I was wondering how I could access the jQuery custom function within a sub function which is defined through an object. Observe:

```
(function($){
    var methods = {
        init    : function ( options ) {
            // getting the variable "data".
            $.each (data, function(itemid, toll){
                $.notification("update", data);
            });
        },
        update  : function ( options ) {
            // ...
        }
    };
    $.fn.notification = function ( method ) {
        if ( methods[method] ) {
            return methods[method].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
        } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
            return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
        }
    };
})(jQuery);
```

The above method, using `$.notification ("update", data);` does not work, because the function is in the middle of being defined. So, how does one access the above function, without repeating code? i.e. writing a function just to update, outside of the `method` variable, and then placing that function within the `update` index of the method variable? Thank you in advanced. `:3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below line to execute it

```
$().notification("update", data);
```